# UNRESOLVED_REFERENCE Unresolved reference: isInitialized

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to use Kotlin's new feature of checking lateinit property status, but got this compile time error `Unresolved reference: isInitialized`

I have configure my build.gradle file with kotlin version of `kotlin_version = '1.2.0-beta-31'`
  (android studio version is 3.0)
and also updated kotlin plugin with same version.
this is my code snippet, where I'm using `isInitialized` check.

also had a reflect library included

```
compile group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', name: 'kotlin-reflect', version: '1.2.0-beta-31'
```

.

```
lateinit var k: SomeObjectType
fun instance(): SomeObjectType {
    if (::k.isInitialized) {
        k = SomeObjectType()
    }
    return k
}
```

Comment: Are you missing the reflect library?

Comment: I had this one   compile group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', name: 'kotlin-reflect', version: '1.2.0-beta-31'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug as reported [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-20774#tab=Linked%20Issues) and is released in [v1.2-rc-1](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/releases/tag/v1.2-rc1)

**Update:** Kotlin 1.2 RC appears to be available as '1.2.0-rc-39', so if you update your plugin and use this version, your issue should be resolved.

As a workaround until you install rc-1, prefixing the variable with `this::` works as can be shown in this project.

```
package com.example.john.so2

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

data class SomeObjectType(val value: String)
lateinit var k: SomeObjectType

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var k: SomeObjectType

    fun instance(): SomeObjectType {

        if (this::k.isInitialized) {
            return k
        } else {
            return SomeObjectType("k was not initialized")
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        println("instance = ${instance()}")
        k = SomeObjectType("k was initialized")
        println("instance = ${instance()}")
    }


}
```

which yields:

```
11-03 19:31:14.496 31982-31982/com.example.john.so2 I/System.out: instance = SomeObjectType(value=k was not initialized)
11-03 19:31:14.496 31982-31982/com.example.john.so2 I/System.out: instance = SomeObjectType(value=k was initialized)
```

BTW, I left my original answer as it highlights the fact that the correct syntax works in "try-online"

Comment: I'm just trying out the final Kotlin 1.2 and 1.2.0 Android Studio 3.0 plugin, and am still seeing the `isInitialized` as red in my code in the IDE, with tooltip: `Unresolved reference: isInitialized`. The code, however, compiles and runs as expected. Attempts to display Kotlin bytecode fails with a NullPointerException on that line.

Comment: I was also seeing `Unresolved reference: isInitialized` after trying this, but that was because I was missing this in my `build.gradle`: `implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.2.10"`

Answer (score 1):

isInitialized is not working for local lateinit var but it is working fine for global ones.

Answer (score 0):

Is your code valid Kotlin code?
I tried the following and it seemed to work as expected.

```
data class SomeObjectType(val value: String) 

lateinit var k: SomeObjectType

fun instance(): SomeObjectType {
    if (::k.isInitialized) {
        return k 
    } else {
        return SomeObjectType("k was not initialized")
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("inst = ${instance()}")
    k = SomeObjectType("was initialized")
    println("inst = ${instance()}")
}
```

producing :

```
inst = SomeObjectType(value=k was not initialized)
inst = SomeObjectType(value=was initialized)
```

When I tried what you have above: (with the added `class SomeObjectType()`

```
class SomeObjectType()
lateinit var k: SomeObjectType
fun instance(): SomeObjectType {
    if (::k.isInitialized) {
        instance = SomeObjectType()
    }
    return instance
}
```

it complains about the `instance = SomeObjectType()` line and the `return instance` line, which I think makes sense to me. Line 5 being the `instance = SomeObjectType()` and line 7 being the `return instance` line.

```
Error:(5, 8) Function invocation 'instance()' expected
Error:(5, 8) Variable expected
Error:(7, 11) Function invocation 'instance()' expected
```

Here are the links to the online examples.
[working example](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/7j4veo27s4s8taonktb9isj7db/seh4mii53ubhq583gakg13tokq),  [broken example](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/dtnhn2c1trjeilji66pkkro2u9/2dtbjng6usiav9c5evl1bptl5t)

Comment: I have already tried online examples and it worked, I tried for String. Also in my android project I copied and pasted it for String type example but I had the same problem

Comment: also I missed variable name in my question, instead of instance should be k, I have updated code snippet

Answer (score 0):

If `isInitialized` appears in red, check that you have upgraded your Kotlin version to >1.2

Check both in your Project and Module Gradle files:

1. In your Project Gradle check the row:

   ext.kotlin_version = "1.2.21"
2. In your Module Gradle check the row:

   compile 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.2.21'

Despite the other comments, in my case it was NOT necessary to add the reflection library:

```
"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlinVersion"
```

Comment: This did not solve it for me. I have: 
ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.21' and compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version", but "isInitialized" appears in red.

Answer (score 0):

> Project_level.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.30'

    ...
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    ...
    }
}
```

> App_level.gradle

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    ...
}
```

> Usage

```
class Foo() {

    lateinit var theVariable: String

    // this is required to access isInitialized
    fun foo() {
        this::theVariable.isInitialized
    }
}
```