# Check if a local lateinit variable is initialized

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-lateinit

Member lateinit variables initialization can be checked with:

```
class MyClass {
    lateinit var foo: Any
    ...
    fun doSomething() {
        if (::foo.isInitialized) {
           // Use foo
        }
    }
}
```

However this syntax doesn't work for local lateinit variables. Lint reports the error: "References to variables aren't supported yet". There should logically be a way to do that since lateinit variables are null internally when uninitialized.

Is there a way to check if local variables are initialized?

Comment: Can't reproduce this. If `foo` is optional You should use a nullable field instead of `lateinit var`. It is intended mostly for field injection or initialization that cannot be done within constructor (for example - Androids `onCreate` call).

Comment: @Pawel But why was local lateinit introduced then?

Comment: Take a look at this question 
 and the answer.  This maybe a duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47052164/unresolved-reference-unresolved-reference-isinitialized/47105843#47105843

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-21163

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Thanks

Comment: You are not showing the code that actually produces the compiler message.  In your code foo is not a local variable and the code you show will work fine in Kotlin 1.2+

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The code you show in your question is actually fine in Kotlin 1.2 and beyond, since foo is an instance variable, **not** a local variable.
The error message you report and mentioned in Alexey's comment (`Unsupported [References to variables aren't supported yet]`) can be triggered by a true local variable, for example in the `doSomethingElse` method below.

```
class MyClass {
    lateinit var foo: Any

    fun doSomething() {
        if (::foo.isInitialized) {  // this is fine to use in Kotlin 1.2+
           // Use foo
        }
    }
    fun doSomethingElse() {
        lateinit var bar: Any

        if (::bar.isInitialized) {  // this is currently unsupported (see link in Alexey's comment.
            // Use bar 
        }

    }

}
```

So it seems like this is currently unsupported.  The only place that comes to mind where a lateinit local would be used would be if the local is variable captured in a lambda?